# Unable to resolve ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, import, package, graphviz

I have been wanting to use imports for Python and tried with pygame and now graphviz, but have kept getting the same error of `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'graphviz'`. When I hover over the error in VSCode, I get `unresolved import 'graphviz'Python(unresolved-import)`. I have tried changing the global environtment by pyenv to 3.7.4 and when I type `python -v` into terminal, it gives me the correct version. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Here is the code snippet:

```
import sys
import os
print(sys.path)
import graphviz
from graphviz import Digraph

dot = Digraph(comment='Test')


dot.node('A', 'Rishi')
dot.node('B', 'Gudli')
dot.node('C', 'Shivraj')

dot.edges(['AB', 'AC'])
dot.edge('B', 'C', constraint='false')
```

Comment: Do you have graphviz installed? If so, how did you install it? Either way, you'll probably want to take a look at [VSCode's directions for using Python packages](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial#_install-and-use-packages).

Answer (score 0):

1) Install graphviz with

```
pip install graphviz
```

2) Are you in the correct virtualenv?

3) Sometimes (and i dont know why) in visual studio I personally can't import some modules. Try using another IDE.